# import javax.xml.transform cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to write some xml generated by my Android app to a file and I'm trying to use javax.xml.transform to do this. Only problem is that javax.xml.transform is not being found by eclipse.

The only options that come up are javax.xml and javax.xml.parsers. Does anyone know what could be going on?

Edit: Just an fyi I have Java JDK 6 update 22 installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found out what to do. If you right click on whatever project your working on and go to properties. Then in the libraries tab click add libraries and add the JRE System Library then it has a bunch of new imports that can be used including javax.xml.transform.

That took forever to find out that simple thing =P. But now I know.

Comment: then it has a bunch of new imports that can be used including javax.xml.transform.? i didn't get this part, I don't see any import?

Answer (score 4):

`javax.xml.transform` is only available in API level 8+.

even if you add the JRE System Libraries, it'll error at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly an android developer but if you have Android project in Eclipse and something is not on the classpath (not in import options) it probably means it won't be available on Android.